# Javascript image cropping different shapes

Tags: jquery, image-processing, jquery-plugins, crop, jcrop

I am starting work on an application that needs image cropping with various shapes for example :  I upload an image and the crosshair selection that the user gets could be of the shape of a human face or a car or shape of love etc. Something similar to https://www.mystickerface.com/gettingstarted. Please take the time to upload a smaple image here.

Are there any out of the box javascripts libraries that I could use for this purpose. Jcrop and some others I saw only give rectangular selection.

Please let me know suggestions on how to go about the implementation.

Answer (score 0):

It can be done with either html5 canvas or and old trick. If you want to "crop" irregular shapes, create an image and fill the irregular shape transparent and the rest same color as the background, then overlay the shape on top of the portion of the image you want to make irregular and if needed use a higher `z-index`.

Check out [How to generate color variations of the product](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9358922/how-to-generate-color-variations-of-the-product/9359131#9359131).